# TypeScript Unable to resolve path (2307)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm building a react-native application. I've spent hours on this problem but nothing has helped me. I'm trying to use tsconfig paths for shortening my long relative imports:

My tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./*",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "module": "commonjs",  
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "paths": {
            "@theme/*": ["./src/theme/*"]
        },
        "strict": true,
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to import a module as follows:

```
import { theme } from '@theme'
```

However I'm getting the following error. This error shows with red underline in VSCode.

```
Cannot find module '@theme' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

But I get this error when I run command eslint as well.

I have also tried adding a package.json with a name property to theme directory, but it doesn't help either:

```
{
    "name": "@theme"
}
```

I use the following versions:

```
"typescript": "^4.1.4"
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"react": "16.13.1",
"eslint": "^6.8.0",

Node version: v12.21.0
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: One more info, I can import and use the module. But the typescript error does not go away. It always tells me module cannot be resolved, even though I use it.

Comment: What package is this? Is this a module you have written yourself or installed?